# How to connect node server with vue socket

Tags: node.js, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using vue.js(Laravel) to connect with my chat node server, its connect socket but emit not work  with function.

```
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/api/message');

        socket.on('connect', function () {

           var mapdata = {chatId: this.chatIdd, userId: this.userIdd}

           socket.emit("joinChat", JSON.stringify(mapdata) ,function(confirmation){
               alert('Work');

                      console.log(confirmation);
              });

        }.bind(this));
           socket.on('msgReceive', function () {


        }.bind(this));
```

alert('Work') Not showing. How can i resolve this?

This is the server side function

```
        socket.on("joinChat", async msg => {
            let objectValue = await JSON.parse(msg);
            chatId = objectValue["chatId"];
            socket.join(chatId);
        });
```

Comment: I update the question with server side code

Answer (score 1):

To use (ack)nowledgements, you have to fire the function.

**Client**

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit("joinChat", {
    chatId: this.chatIdd,
    userId: this.userIdd
  }, function(confirmation) {
    //alert('Work');
    console.log(confirmation); // From server
  });
}.bind(this));
```

**Server**

```
socket.on('joinChat', (msg, ack) => {
  if (msg.chatId) {
    socket.join(msg.chatId);
    if (typeof ack === 'function') ack('From server')
  }
});
```